# Expanding the abbreviated words from a file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new at working with files in haskell.I wrote a code to check for occurence of words in a `.c` file. words are listed in a `.txt` file .

for example:

```
abbreviations.txt
ix=index
ctr=counter
tbl=table
```

Another file is:

```
 main.c
 main ()
 {
ix = 1
for (ctr =1; ctr < 10; ctr++)
{ 
   tbl[ctr] = ix
}
}
```

on encountering `ix` it should be expanded to `index` and same for `ctr` and `tbl`.

This is the code I wrote to check for occurrences(not yet to replace the encountered words)

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import Data.Set

main = do
    s <- getLine
    f <- readFile "abbreviations.txt"
    g <- readFile s
    let dict = fromList (lines f)
    mapM_ (spell dict) (words g)

spell d w =  when (w `member` d) (putStrLn w)
```

On executing the code it is giving no output.

Instead of the upper code,I tried reading a file using `hgetLine` then converting it into list of words using `words`

```
        getLines' h = do
           isEOF <- hIsEOF h
           if isEOF then
            return ()
           else
            do
             line <- hGetLine h
             list<-remove (return (words line))
             getLines' h
           --  print  list
   main = do
       inH <- openFile "abbreviations.txt" ReadMode
       getLines' inH
       hClose inH


   remove [] =  []
    remove (x:xs)| x == "=" = remove xs
                       | otherwise = x:remove (xs)
```

But its giving me errors relating to IO() ,is there any other way in which I could do the following.

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Use ``if w `member` d then putStrLn d else return ()`` (the else is mandatory) or  use `when` instead.

Comment: I did     `spell d w = when (w `member` d) (putStrLn w) `  ,still its gives no output.

Comment: Check the type of dict in ghci. I suspect you're not generating the map as you expect

Comment: It would be easy for other to read your code if you could also add your import statements. From where exactly `member` and `fromList` is coming ?

Comment: `member` and `fromList` belong to Data.set

Comment: Does "abbreviations.txt" still contain lines that say "ix=index"? In which case, your dictionary contains not "ix" or "index" but "ix=index"?

Comment: Yes,true.It contains the abbreviated words and their actual meaning in the given format.

Answer (score 3):

First, there is a problem with your spell function. It should also have an else clause with it:

```
spell :: (Show a, Ord a) => Set a -> a -> IO ()
spell d w = if (w `member` d) 
            then print d
            else return ()
```

Also, note that I have changed your `putStrLn` to `print` and added a type signature to your code.

> On executing the code it is giving no output.

That's because, it's always going to the else clause in your `spell` function. If you try to trace up the execution of your program, then you will note that, your `dict` variable will actually contain this Set: `["ctr=counter","ix=index","tbl=table"]` and it doesn't contains the words of the file `main.c`. I hope this will be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: Instead of the upper code,I tried reading a file using `hgetLine` then converting it into list of words using `words`